# How can I get all list of scopes in ActiveRecord 3.x

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am using ActiveRecord with Rails 3.

I defined scopes in my model. How can I get the list of all scopes of that model?

Previously I could use `Model.scopes`

OR
Can I check a scope is defined or not? Something like `Model.scope_defined?("scope_name")`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see if a scope is defined or not this way

```
Model.send(:valid_scope_name?, :scope_name)
```

it will return `true` if it does exist and `nil` if it does not.

If you check the source code of [`valid_scope_name?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/valid_scope_name?), you see that you can just test it using `respond_to?` and then avoid the logging part.

```
Model.respond_to?(scope_name, true)
```

Comment: No. there is no `scopes` method in AR 3.x

Comment: Thanks! Ok. but respond_to? doesn't check whether it is a `scope` or an attribute of the Model. If I have `some_attribute` in my Model. It gives `true`. I want to check only scopes. Hope you got my concern.

Comment: it does not test for attribute since it's class level. `Model.respond_to?` and `Model.new.respond_to?` are different.

Comment: but declaring class attributes is the same as declaring methods don't you think? Since your cattr_reader will create the getter/setter method. If you have a method with the same name as your attribute, it will override the getter or the getter will override the method depending on the declaring order. You can check Model.methods.include?(your_attribute).

Comment: I don't get you. See, I have class attributes `attr1` and `attr2` and I have scopes `scope1` and `scope2`. I want to check my scope_param is in `scope1` or `scope2`. Sometime I might get `arrt1` as scope_param and I should identify `attr1` is not a scope in my model. got?

Comment: There is no difference between a class method, a class attribute, and a scope in Rails 3.

Comment: oh! So all the class attributes are considered as scope in AR3 :( and I should rework on my infrastructure. :P

Comment: Word of caution - that's a good point made above that all "valid scope name" does is check if the model responds to the method. I was on the verge of using it to provide filtering functionality to the tables in our application by just passing the user paramater (?filter=pending) straight to the model. If I'd done that, the user would have been able to just pass (?filter=destroy_all) and it's bye bye database!

Comment: To avoid the problem that @MikeyHogarth shows us, we can save a whitelist of scopes and check it before we'll make the call.