# Default scope in ActiveResource model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

I am using `ActiveResource` to implement client side backend. In server side there is API and some models have scopes. 
What is the best way to use these scopes in `ActiveResource` models?

For example: server side has model `Track` with scope `:active_tracks`. I have in the client side model named `ActiveTrack`. What should I do in `ActiveTrack` model to get tracks from API scoped by `:active_tracks` (by default) only, not all tracks?

My solution is:

I added a params[:scope] parameter on the client side.

At server side TracksController I did:

```
custom_scope = params[:scope] if params[:scope].exist?
Track.respond_to?(custom_scope) ? Track.send(custom_scope).all : Track.all
```

I use `Track.all` because:

- if there is no such scope in server side I need to get result like there is no scope was send
- server has a default pagination

Is it a good solution or not?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution as well, but this method is dangerous as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616175/how-can-i-get-all-list-of-scopes-in-activerecord-3-x . Somebody could add `?scope=delete_all` to the url and it would be passed to the model.